# dyld: Library not loaded on kivy installation

Tags: python, kivy

I have upgraded my `python version 2.7` to `3.4` then tried to install `kivy library` with command `python setup.py install.` But I am getting an error below.

```
dyld: Library not loaded:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/Python   Referenced
from: /usr/bin/python   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/Python: no matching
architecture in universal wrapper
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/Python: no matching
architecture in universal wrapper Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: How did you install kivy?

Comment: Your default Python version seems to be 3.3, not 3.4. Can you check with `Python -V`?

Comment: I downloaded kivy source package and followed the steps given by kivvy documentation  (http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html). I am getting this error on the step command "python setup.py install" .

Answer (score 0):

You mention Python 3.4 in your initial question, but the log shows Python 3.3. Make sure that you've installed Kivy into the Python version you want to use, and that you are running it from the Python version you installed it into.